# Drag and drop the shape of graphs

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to drag and drop the shape of graphs in Excel?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:
-if I click and hold the graph I can drag it up and down
-if I click on a point on the graph and then click and hold on another point, I will drag an interval of the graph up and down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you are asking for is "Interactive charting". The Excel VBA charting interface draws the entire chart based the parameters you define for it. It doesn't have an interface to manipulate the individual components of the chart thru VBA. (Something like move line vertice to new point). In addition, the points of the graph are based on spreadsheet values. So it would have to detect your mouse events over the chart, convert those movements to the scale used in the chart to reverse calculate a value and then change the associated cell in the spreadsheet. And then a graph repaint of the entire chart would be requested. This total repaint would look pretty choppy.